# Installation of Opencv4 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv

how are you ? I am currently a tutorial on the installation of opencv4 with ubuntu 18.04 LTS on [pyimagesearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgPAt.jpg). But in step 4 I have some error.

1.) The python3 section is actually missing so the Interpeter does not point to the Python 3 binary
2.) for the CMake output the "non free algorithms" are not installed.

For Installation I use Python 3.6.9, numpy 1.18.4, opencv4.0.0
Following the execution of the following script:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = / usr / local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES = ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES = OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE = ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH = ~ / opencv_contrib / modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = ~ / .virtualenvs / cv / bin / python \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES = ON ..
```

Now I had to have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgPAt.jpg)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove spaces on every side of `/` :

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX =/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES = ON \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES = OFF \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE = ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH = ~/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = ~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES = ON ..
```

Comment: Bonjour, j'ai pu regler le problème en réalité au niveau de PYTHON_EXECUTABLE je devais mettre ma version de python _(python3)_ et non python donc j'aurai: 

'-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE= ~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3'